# How to get device id in ionic by using cordova plugin?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, uuid, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a **hybrid ionic app**.

I want to get the device id of a android device. I installed **cordova plugin**, included **cordova.min.js** file.

I tried by this code, still not displaying anything.

Is there any other way to get device id?

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('DeviceController', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $cordovaDevice) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
$scope.$apply(function() {

var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();
$scope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer;
$scope.model = device.model;
$scope.platform = device.platform;
$scope.uuid = device.uuid;
});
});
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="DeviceController">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Device Information</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="item">
                        Manufacturer : {{manufacturer}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        Model : {{model}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        Platform : {{platform}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        UUID : {{uuid}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you **have installed** the device plugin, just do `window.device.uuid` (after you've received the device ready event).

**EDIT**

Looking again at your code, you don't need the platform ready in the controller and I am not sure if it's going to fire like that. Also why do you call apply in there? How about this:

```
.controller('DeviceController', function () {
    alert(window.device.uuid);
});
```

Comment: still not working, Is it necessary that device has to be connected to internet to get the uuid?

Comment: @PrathikKotian no you don't need to be connected to get the uid. What is exactly the problem? Is the window.device object undefined?

Answer (score 0):

you can add below plugin in your project [UniqueDeviceID](https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID)

and add below line in ondevice ready

window.plugins.uniqueDeviceID.get(success, fail);

add success and failure function in your code

```
function success(){
    alert(uuid);
 }



function fail(error){
 alert("error " + error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Point to note here is ng-cordova.js internally calls the methods and API's od native cordova so it is very important to install the cordova plugins separately even after you install the ng-cordova.js. Then i initialized the device in app.module.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  $scope.deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();
});
```

and i called the method in my intro controller

```
$scope.getDeviceInfo = function() {
  alert($scope.deviceInformation.uuid);
}
```

Or go through http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/ will help you..

Answer (score 0):

I got it, The code is perfecr, nothing wrong in that, even the plugin is installed properly. The problem was ng-cordova.min.js. I just downloaded the newest version of ng-cordova.min.js. And its working perfectly.
Thank you everyone.
This might help others.